# Finding the subspace of $V = P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need help with the following question. I have tried to solve it multiple times but found no success.

Determine if the set is a subspace of the indicated vector space:

$W=$ $\{p(t) \in P_3 \mid p(1) = p(2)\}; V= P_3. $

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you know in general how to show that a set is a subspace of a vector space?

Comment: Yes, I do but I cannot seem to decipher this particular kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $W$ is a vector subspace, we must show it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Addition of elements of $P_3$:

$p_a+p_b$ is defined so that $(p_a+p_b)(t) = p_a(t)+p_b(t)$ for all $t$; in particular, if $p_a,p_b \in W,$

then$(p_a+p_b)  (1) = p_a(1)+p_b(1)=p_a(2)+p_b(2)=(p_a+p_b )(2)$, so $p_a+p_b \in W.$

Scalar multiplication is also defined point-wise, so that $(c p)(t)= c p(t)$; in particular, if $p \in W$,

then $(cp)(1)=cp(1)=cp(2)=(cp)(2),$ so $cp\in W.$  Thus, $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: Thank you so much.